# data not binding in jqgrid in chrome browser, whereas in internet explorer 8, it binds the data

Tags: html, jquery

Am using JQuery Ajax to call a webservice to bind the data in JQgrid. However, data is binding in IE8 (Browser) correctly, but not binding in Chrome & Firefox Browsers. Here is my Jquery code.

```
$("#datagrid").jqGrid({
            url: "service url",
            type: "GET",
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
            datatype: "json",
            //colNames:['Id','MID','Status','DocNo','VendorID','InvoiceNo','VendorName','Amount','Type','DocDate','DueDate','ClDoc','Texxt','UserName','Currency','ConCode','Region','Stat','Comb','Comments'],

            colNames:['Id','MID','Status','VendorID','VendorName','InvoiceNo','DocDate','Amount','DocNo','Type','DueDate','ClDoc','Text','UserName','Currency','ConCode','Region','Stat','Process','Comb','Comments'],
            colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:50,sortable:true},
    {name:'mid',index:'mid', width:50, sortable:true},
    {name:'status',index:'status', width:70, sortable:true},
    {name:'vendorid',index:'vendorid', width:90, sortable:false,align:"left"},
    {name:'vendorname',index:'vendorname', width:170, sortable:false,align:"left"},
    {name:'invoiceno',index:'invoiceno', width:130, sortable:false,align:"left"},   
    {name:'docdate',index:'docdate', width:100, sortable:false},
    {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, sortable:false,align:"Right"},
    {name:'docno',index:'docno', width:100, sortable:false},
    {name:'typee',index:'typee', width:50, sortable:false},
    {name:'duedate',index:'duedate', width:100, sortable:false},
    {name:'cldoc',index:'cldoc', width:80, sortable:false},
    {name:'text',index:'texxt', width:70, sortable:false},
    {name:'username',index:'username', width:100, sortable:false},
    {name:'currency',index:'currency', width:80, sortable:false},
    {name:'concode',index:'concode', width:80, sortable:false},
    {name:'region',index:'region', width:70, sortable:false},
    {name:'stat',index:'stat', width:60, sortable:false},
    {name:'process',index:'process', width:60, sortable:false},
    {name:'combination',index:'combination', width:60, sortable:true},
    {name:'comments',index:'comments', width:150, height:20, edittype:'textarea', sortable:false, editable: true,
            editoptions: {disabled: false, size:50, resizable:true}}
    ],

       viewrecords: true    
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved.

Cause: If you are working in local system (i.e, in D or E drive), it wont allow to bind data in grid in Chrome or FF browser. But it works fine in IE.

Solution: we have to convert those HTML, JS and CSS files into WAR file and deploy those files, and then it works fine for all browsers.

Thanks.